# How to 'read-only' a SQLite3 database that is being written to?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

```
ec2-ubuntu-sqlite3
```

A Python script is writing tick-data to an SQLite3 database. I am accessing the database for this purpose using the following:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('tick.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout=20,isolation_level=None)

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')
```

Simultaneously (this is a separate script runs every minute), I am reading (only) the database using `pandas`.

```
conn_tick = sqlite3.connect('tick.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout=20,
                                        isolation_level=None)

select_statement = 'select timestamp,close from %sfut where "timestamp" > "%s"' % (bnf, lasttimestamp)

tdf = pd.read_sql(select_statement, conn_tick)

conn_tick.close()
```

When I try to get an idea of how much time the second command takes, it is usually in the 10-12 second range, number of rows: 297. However when the number of rows is higher say 1000+. The time increase to 90 seconds.

I believe this might be due to the write process locking the database?

Should I be looking into Postgres? Is something in my code the problem which I can't figure out?

### Edit 2

The write code:

```
inst_token_list = [260105, 256265, 259, 13177346, 13176834, 486915]

def tick_entry(inst,timestamp,ltp):
    if inst == 260105:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO bnftick (timestamp, close) VALUES (?,?)',
                  (timestamp,ltp))
    elif inst == 259:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO usdinrtick (timestamp, close) VALUES (?,?)',
                  (timestamp, ltp))

    conn.commit()

def tick_entry1(inst,timestamp,ltp, bid, ask):
    if inst == 13177346:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO niftyfut (timestamp, close, bid, ask) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
                  (timestamp, ltp, bid, ask))
    elif inst == 13176834:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO bnffut (timestamp, close, bid, ask) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
                  (timestamp, ltp, bid, ask))

    conn.commit()

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    global c, conn
    for t in ticks:
        if t['instrument_token'] == 260105:
            timestamp = t['timestamp']
            ltp = t['last_price']
            inst = t['instrument_token']

            try:
                tick_entry(inst,timestamp,ltp)
            except:
                # print('problem with db')
                pass
        elif t['instrument_token'] == 13177346:
            timestamp = t['timestamp']
            ltp = t['last_price']
            inst = t['instrument_token']
            bid = t['depth']['buy'][0]['price']
            ask = t['depth']['sell'][0]['price']
            # print(t, bid, ask)
            try:
                tick_entry1(inst,timestamp,ltp,bid,ask)
            except:
                print('Problem with new')
                pass
        elif t['instrument_token'] == 13176834:
            timestamp = t['timestamp']
            ltp = t['last_price']
            inst = t['instrument_token']
            bid = t['depth']['buy'][0]['price']
            ask = t['depth']['sell'][0]['price']
            # print(t['instrument_token'], bid, ask)
            try:
                tick_entry1(inst,timestamp,ltp,bid,ask)
            except:
                print('Problem with new 1')
                pass


def on_connect(ws, response):
    
    ws.subscribe(inst_token_list)


    ws.set_mode(ws.MODE_FULL, inst_token_list)

# Assign the callbacks.
kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
kws.on_connect = on_connect
# kws.on_close = on_close

# Infinite loop on the main thread. Nothing after this will run.
# You have to use the pre-defined callbacks to manage subscriptions.
kws.connect()
```

### Edit

As @ipaleka pointed out:

> On the other hand, read performance deteriorates as the WAL file grows in size since each reader must check the WAL file for the content and the time needed to check the WAL file is proportional to the size of the WAL file. The wal-index helps find content in the WAL file much faster, but performance still falls off with increasing WAL file size. Hence, to maintain good read performance it is important to keep the WAL file size down by running checkpoints at regular intervals.

How much this effect would have has per, say, 10mb?

Looking up how to set checkpoints now.

Comment: Try with: `select_statement = 'select timestamp,close from %sfut where DATETIME(timestamp) > "%s"' % (bnf, lasttimestamp)`

Comment: @ipaleka no noticeable difference in performance, could it be that the write process is blocking/locking the database from being read?

Comment: Your table has that few rows and it's taking that long? Or is that just the rows being returned from a much larger table? If the latter, is there an index on the timestamp column?

Comment: And measure the time to fetch the rows using just sqlite, to see how much overhead pandas has.

Comment: @Shawn No index on timestamp column. Its a much larger table(400K plus rows). I am seeing a strange issue when the write script is not running all the processes are way faster. I am going to try and run the script on my home/office computer rather than ec2 micro, may be RAM is an issue. Honestly running out of ideas. I checked each statement separately, now that tick data is not coming in, the select is taking not more than 0.5 seconds to select 40k rows.

Comment: Reading [this](https://www3.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) reveals the problem - you set write-ahead logging for all your connections with that command.

Comment: @ipaleka I thought that is the proper way to allow multiple read access to the database while writing to it. I am an absolute newbie to database's in general. What would be a better/faster way to do it?

Comment: "On the other hand, read performance deteriorates as the WAL file grows in size since each reader must check the WAL file for the content and the time needed to check the WAL file is proportional to the size of the WAL file. The wal-index helps find content in the WAL file much faster, but performance still falls off with increasing WAL file size. Hence, to maintain good read performance it is important to keep the WAL file size down by running checkpoints at regular intervals." Now to research how to set checkpoints.

Comment: Just use defaults - and that has been the rule of thumb for novices not only for databases - don't use that pragma command.

Comment: @ipaleka Do you mean I should remove `c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=wal')`, would this still allow me to read the database while it is being written to? Reading more but your insight would help a lot.

Comment: Yes, just use defaults as smart people defined those defaults counting that novice users will be using their tools. That pragma command is something you'll never need.

Comment: @Sid  How often are you writing to the database.  Update the question with the code that writes, since that certainly is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Sid  I am not advocating turning off WAL mode, but if you do decide to turn WAL mode off (even if just for comparison testing), be aware that WAL mode is persistent (as mentioned in the same webpages linked above).  Simply excluding the PRAGMA call at this point *would not change the WAL mode*, rather you would have to execute `PRAGMA journal_mode = DELETE` to reset the default behavior.  (And despite my disagreement with ipaleka's philosophy about defaults, I still recommend testing this to see how it compares.  But I also suggest trying the explicit checkpointing as already mentioned.)

Comment: @Sid  See [this pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint) for initiating manual checkpoints.

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks. Added the write code above. The data comes in on every tick, which can theoretically be very high, but lets assume every second. I have shortened the number of instruments.
I am going to test the WAL mode off tomorrow. For explicit checkpoints I will go through the pragma posted by you. Thank you so much. I would greatly appreciate if I may bother both of you(@ipaleka) tomorrow as well.